How to capture and update the highest & lowest value ever entered into a cell in google sheets?
I have a google sheet that tracks stock values and the data is regularly feed into a cell from Google Finance and other 3rd party extensions.  Based on that data I display the current margin/profit of a stock option.   I would like to capture what the high and low of that margin is while this stock option remains active based on the changing values fed into the sheet.  I would like this to be true for each new stock option I enter... one row = one option entered and once the option is closed/done, I then copy and paste it, values only onto another sheet as a historical log.
Example... the option currently has a 20% margin, but since I entered this option into the sheet... it's been as high as a 60% margin and as a low as -35% margin.   Right now I only know that from my observations, but I would like the sheet to automatically capture and update the high and low if need be every time it receives an updated value for this cell containing the option margin.
I've attached a sample demo sheet.   The margin value that is fed into the sheet is highlighted in column T and the low and high columns are there in column V & W.   Please help me accurately automatically populate columns V & W as column T changes dynamically overtime.  Thanks!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jx3kMqj7W_D1_C3Ft1TeEU2s6pZznFzXXPr8jjxZ9SU/edit?usp=sharing
I haven't tried much yet, one site suggested using the Aggregate function but that only seemed to work for telling me max or min of a dataset range.

If you are populating your data using the function GOOGLEFINANCE(ticker, [attribute], [start_date], [end_date|num_days], [interval]), then you can get historical data adding "high" as an attribute. Add a start and end date to get the historical high between those dates.
This will return a set of data for each high between the dates you input. Then just get the max of the "High" column from the array.
The complete function looks like:
=MAX(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("STZ", "high", DATE(2024,2,12), DATE(2024,3,8), 1), ,2))

Thanks, I appreciate the thinking on this one.   The trouble is that I'm doing option spreads which google finance doesn't directly support as they are combinations of various option purchases so you can't pull the high that way... so I use another 3rd party source (www.marketdata.app) to pull the current values.   Any way to capture the high of what comes in that way?   Or do you know a way to pull the high for a credit spread in google finance?  my understanding is that googlefinance doesn't offer it.

I unfortunately don't know enough about finance to be able to tell if Google Finance or the Market Data API could give you what you needed. One thing you might want to look at is the onEdit(e) function. This function runs every time a cell (or range of cells) is edited in a spreadsheet link. You could probably use this to update columns V and W if column T is updated with values higher or lower than what was currently in column T.
